# remove or append a kexalgorithms or a hostkeyalgorithms in "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"

Tags: linux, encryption, sshd

I need to modify the default list of kexalgorithms or a hostkeyalgorithms in "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" by explicitly mentioning both the not required algos as well as the required ones.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/sshd_config.5.html  tells:-
if the specified value begins with a ‘+’ character, then the specified methods will be appended to the default set instead of replacing them.  If the specified value begins with a ‘-’ character, then the specified methods (including wildcards) will be removed from the default set instead of replacing them.

For eg: I need to remove just the diffie-hellman* from the default list, so in "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" i tried these 3 syntax individually

```
KexAlgorithms -diffie-hellman*
KexAlgorithms -"diffie-hellman*"
KexAlgorithms "-diffie-hellman*"
```

However none of these syntax is working..